Um dos elementos não aparece no DataFrame
       BEEF3    BOVA11      PETR4       WEGE3
0   3.955020    87.900002   8.526197    8.310699
1   4.048445    88.000000   8.735277    8.500209
2   4.204155    88.500000   8.760082    8.597277
3   4.180799    88.480003   8.898286    8.463234
4   4.134086    88.830002   8.845132    8.393901

pesos= np.random.random(len(dataset.columns) - 1)
pesos= pesos / pesos.sum() 
colunas= dataset.columns[1: ]
acoes_pesos= pd.DataFrame(data= {'Ações': colunas, 'Pesos': pesos * 100})

Ações       Pesos
0   BOVA11  44.829556
1   PETR4   39.847775
2   WEGE3   15.322668

No output não aparece o peso de BEEF3. Começa da segunda ação, que é BOVA11. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Remova o -1 de pesos= np.random.random(len(dataset.columns) - 1) e teste...

Olá, Paulo! Ao removê-lo recebi a seguinte mensagem: ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

Detalhando o comentário, pois talvez minha explicação não tenha ficado clara.
>>> data = {"BEEF": [1,2,3,4,5], "BOVA": [4,5,6,7,8], "PETR": [7,8,9,10,11], "WEGE": [10,11,12,13,14]}
>>> dataset = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> pesos = np.random.random(len(dataset.columns))  # Aqui é só para tirar o -1
>>> pesos = pesos / pesos.sum()
>>> colunas = dataset.columns
>>> acoes_pesos = pd.DataFrame(data= {'Ações': colunas, 'Pesos': pesos * 100})

A saída neste caso é:
>>> acoes_pesos
  Ações      Pesos
0  BEEF  11.416342
1  BOVA  51.741320
2  PETR  13.429158
3  WEGE  23.413179


Interessante como quase toda resposta que dou à uma pergunta, recebe dois votos negativos já no dia seguinte da mesma. Mais interessante ainda, que os que votam negativo, NUNCA explicam o motivo para que eu possa melhorar a resposta. Será que são bots? Ou apenas pessoas que não se preocupam em contribuir respondendo às dúvidas alheias e apenas votam negativo por pura "diversão"? Uma pena que os votos não são abertos para vermos se há um padrão...

Muito obrigado, Paulo! Deu certo! Eu nem sabia desses votos. Até pensei que tivesse feito algo de errado.
